# LibGDX touchDown touchUp on different Actors

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my LibGDX game, I have a raster of clickable Actors. I want the player to be able to swipe across them and get the Actor where the **swipe stops**.

I don't want a `GestureListener`, the only thing I need is a touchUp event on the touchDown generated on another Actor. For example: think about Androids login screen where you swipe a pattern to unlock, but I only need an event for the last dot/Actor.

I have tried using `touchDown` / `touchUp`, but the event always fires on the Actor where the `touchDown` occurred.

A fine solution would be to get events for every Actor hit by the swipe, and then get a global `touchUp` event. Is this possible in a relatively accessible way - eg. without writing a whole new InputListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `touchUp()` of your listener, call `hit` on the parent WidgetGroup of all your clickable Actors to see which one the finger is over when it is released. Note that since you're adding the actors to the group, the group needs to be added to the stage instead of adding the widgets to the stage directly. And remember that an Actor's X and Y are relative to its parent.

```
final WidgetGroup parent = new WidgetGroup();

InputListener inputListener = new InputListener(){
    private final Vector2 tmp = new Vector2();

    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }

    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        event.getTargetActor().localToParentCoordinates(tmp.set(x, y));
        Actor releaseOverActor = parent.hit(tmp.x, tmp.y, true);
        if (releaseOverActor != null){
            //doSomethingTo(releaseOverActor);
        }
    }
}

for (Actor clickable : clickableActors){
    parent.add(clickable);
    clickable.addListener(inputListener);
}
```

The above is a little bit simplified. You might want to return true one `touchDown` only if pointer 0 is used, for example.

Comment: Works! Is there a way to send events to the Actors who get swiped over in the process? Also, `event.getTargetActor().localToParentCoordinates(tmp.set(x, y));` should be `final Vector2 pos = event.getTarget().localToParentCoordinates(new Vector2(x, y));` (ignore the fact that I didn't use a global variable, the method name is different). I don't know what libGDX version you're using, I'm on 1.9.3.

Comment: I could probably override `touchDragged` and then call the hit method... But I guess that wouldn't be very optimized as it will spam create Vector2 objects, project them and try to find an Actor every time the touch will be moved.

Comment: I see the typo I made with getTargetActor, but why would you want to needlessly allocate and deallocate vectors? With my way, there is no GC spamming even if you use it in touchDragged, although I don't see the purpose of that unless you want to also tint actors while hovering over them.

Comment: Yea I was just testing, it will be changed, and yea I want to tint them. Does the `localToParentCoordinates` apply its calculation to the given vector?

Comment: It's explained in the documentation of the method.